# Database is updated sucessfully, but API returns 500 error

Tags: javascript, express, sqlite, knex.js, superagent

I am currently working on a project that is using Javascript with Node.js, Express, SuperAgent and KnexJS (database framework for Sqlite3). My problem is this:

When I submit data for updates via my API route using the PUT method, my database is updating successfully, but my console returns this error:

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/user/contracts/ 500 (unknown)
Error: unknown
    at Request.<anonymous> (client.js:423)
    at Request.Emitter.emit (index.js:133)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (client.js:735)
```

Here is some snippets of my API, Routes, and DB code.

**api.js**

```
const request = require('superagent')

const updateUserContract = (callback, id, contractData) => {
  request
    .put('http://localhost:3000/user/contracts/' + id)
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .send(contractData)
    .end(function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err)
      } else {
        callback(null, "Status: 200")
      }
    })
}

module.exports = { updateUserContract }
```

**routes.js**

```
router.put('/contracts/:id', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id
  var signatureUrl = req.body.signature_url
  db.signContract(id, signatureUrl).then((result) => {
    res.sendStatus(result)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).send(err)
  })
})
```

**db.js**

```
function signContract (id, signatureUrl) {
  return knex('contracts').where('id', id)
  .update({ signature_url: signatureUrl }).into('contracts')
}
```

Comment: Check your server log for the reason for the 500 error.

Comment: @Barmar I just had a check then. Sorry still new to this to a degree. I didn't see anything about errors. This is what I got back.

 `express:router dispatching PUT /user/contracts/21 +3s
  express:router query  : /user/contracts/21 +2ms
  express:router expressInit  : /user/contracts/21 +0ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /user/contracts/21 +0ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /user/contracts/21 +0ms
  express:router trim prefix (/user) from url /user/contracts/21 +0ms
  express:router router /user : /user/contracts/21 +0ms
  express:router dispatching PUT /contracts/21 +0ms`

Comment: strip down the ".into('contracts')", you already provided him in knex("contracts")

Comment: about your error, you're sending sql status as if it where an http status. my best guess is, it's being "promoted" to an error 500. try simply req.send("OK"), it will deliver status 200 as default.

Comment: @Sombriks you are a legend! That got it going! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Was answered by @Sombriks. "about your error, you're sending sql status as if it where an http status. my best guess is, it's being "promoted" to an error 500. try simply req.send("OK"), it will deliver status 200 as default".